# SQLite datatbase data not inserting

Tags: android, json, sqlite

In my android code I am inserting some data to database from gcm intent.It is working when I am inserting without checking any condition.When I check the first element of the json object received with if statement data are not inserting.I think some error with if condition.please help me

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("title");


        if (message ==  "instru"){
        String message1 = intent.getExtras().getString("price");
        String message2 = intent.getExtras().getString("price1");
        String message3 = intent.getExtras().getString("price2");
        String message4 = intent.getExtras().getString("price3");
        String message5 = intent.getExtras().getString("price4");
        DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(getApplicationContext());
        int count = db.getRowCount_1();
        if(count > 0){
            db.resetTables_1();
        }
        db.addUser_1(message1,message2,message3,message4,message5);
       }
        else if(message == "signal"){
            //else {
            String message1 = intent.getExtras().getString("date");
            String message2 = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
            String message3 = intent.getExtras().getString("buy");
            String message4 = intent.getExtras().getString("stop");
            String message5 = intent.getExtras().getString("tv");
            String message6 = intent.getExtras().getString("tp");
            String message7 = intent.getExtras().getString("res");
            DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(getApplicationContext());
            DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(getApplicationContext());
            int count = db.getRowCount_2();
            if(count > 0){
                db.resetTables_2();
            }
            db.addUser_2(message1,message2,message3,message4,message5,message6,message7);


        }
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }
```

different json objects recieved

```
$message = array(
"title" => "instru",
"price" => $trade1,
"price1" => "$trade2",
"price2" => "$trade3",
"price3" => "$trade4",
"price4" => "$date");

$message = array(
        "title" => "signal",
        "date" => $date1,
        "name" => $signal_name,
        "buy" => $price,
        "stop" => $stop,
        "tv" => $trig_value,
        "tp" => $profit,       
        "res" => $result,
    );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

In java, to compare `String`, You need to use `equals()` instead of `==`

```
if (message.equals("instru"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
message.equals("instru")
```

instead of

```
message ==  "instru"
```

Same goes valid for 'message == "signal"'

**Even better**

Use

```
  "instru".equals(message)
```

Since `message can be`null` in some situations

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
 (message == "signal")
```

for comparing two Strings.

Using == operator in Java programming for compare two Strings its bad thing. So you need to use ***equals()*** or ***equalsIgnoreCase()***. So it will be

```
message.equals("signal")
```

or

```
message.equalsIgnoreCase("signal")
```